# HighCharts - Clicking legend highlights the column

Tags: javascript, android, kotlin, highcharts

I want to disable all action when clicking a legend item.

So far i managed to disable the column hide/appear animation by doing this

```
            events: {
                legendItemClick: function(){return false}
            }
```

or in Android:

```
        events = HIEvents().apply {
            legendItemClick = HIFunction("function() { return false; }")
        }
```

but now when i click on of the legends items it just gets highlighted while the others go into the background like this

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to disable `inactive` and `hover` states:

```
  series: [{
    ...,
    states: {
      inactive: {
        enabled: false
      },
      hover: {
        enabled: false
      }
    }
  }]
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/7s1bkw8v/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.pie.states